# pagination : why it's still run while the page is not match?

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination

I want to scrape data from a website, but first I want to get the page with pagination. Here I'm using python as a program language, and I already got this code. But when I run it, it doesn't work properly. the result must be stopped when response.url didn't match with expected_url. Is there someone know how to solve it? Please help, thank you.
Here is the code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

count = 0
url = "http://www.belanjamimo.net/foundation-bb-cream/?o=a&s=%d"


def get_url(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    return urllib.request.urlopen(req)

expected_url = url % count
response = get_url(expected_url)

while (response.url == expected_url):
    print("GET {0}".format(expected_url))
    count += 9
    expected_url = url % count
    response = get_url(expected_url)
```

Comment: it will never stop since your condition will always be True in on this website, it can be called even if there is no data look at http://www.belanjamimo.net/foundation-bb-cream/?o=a&s=63

Comment: How to stop it when it reach the end of total page?

Comment: at the end of the wihle loop you could check if the "next page button" list element  is disabled and add a break statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below approach to exhaust all the items in different pages and break out of loop when there is no more items available.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.belanjamimo.net/foundation-bb-cream/?o=a&s={}"

page = 0
while True:
    res = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    items = soup.select(".product-block h2 a")
    if len(items)<=1:break  #check out if there is any product still available
    for item in items:
        print(item.text)

    page+=9
```

Comment: I've already try this code, and add some code to get the attribute.. so, for example the web has 5 pages only, but why it is still print 6 pages? @SIM

Comment: You surely have used the script in the wrong way. You can use this line ***`print(res.url)`*** just after this line ***`if len(items)<=1:break`*** to find out whether it is giving you the right count of url containing data. Thanks for your quick reply by the way.

Comment: it's work for the web I mention in the question, but it doesn't work at different web..is it because every web has different settings?